# Spring, JpaRepository: Query for entity with composite id

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a strange behaviour on my JpaRepository:

***Case A:***

```
public interface RouteRepository  extends JpaRepository<Route, SomeComposedId> {

   @Query("SELECT DISTINCT r.name  FROM Route r")
   List<String> findNames();
}
```

***Case B:***

```
public interface RouteRepository  extends JpaRepository<Route, SomeComposedId> {

   @Query("SELECT DISTINCT name  FROM Route")
   List<String> findNames();
}
```

I am unable to start spring boot app for **CaseA**, however when I remove **'r'**  (**CaseB**) everything works.

Strange is that I used **CaseB** all the time, but I recently change **simple id -> composed id** and that started the problem.

Here is the console output:

```
Error creating bean with name 'routeRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.martoma.cd.db.repo.RouteRepository.findNames()!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1225) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:552) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at com.martoma.CdApplication.main(CdApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What is the complete and exact error stack trace?

Comment: I have added the console output.

Comment: But it still doesn't contain the validation error.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, in issue desc., I am able to compile the project, but I can't start spring boot application.

Comment: I don't have any other output except one, which I already added to the issue.

Comment: @TomasMarik How about `@Query("SELECT DISTINCT r.name  FROM Route as r")` Note the `Route as r`

Comment: Thank for advice, but I am more curious why Case A doesn't work for composite Id. I switched back to simple Id and now I can use Case A. - Strange

Comment: This probably doesn't have much to do with the fact you're using a composite ID. But without seeing the code of the Route entity, nor the validation error message, it's hard to say why you get that error.